# How to create screensaver during client gets data from server?

Tags: javascript, angular, web

An Angular application weighs over 5 mb in production. First time, when client asks page from server it takes some time, during this process user sees a blank white page.

Is it possible to create screensaver until client gets data?

Comment: did you consider to lazy load your modules? you definitely have gain from this

Comment: That is good point, I will check out this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1 - clean & tidy:** Create a new loading component and set that as your root component, and offload all of the loading work  from your root component to that new component via [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

**Option 2 - quick & dirty:** You can edit your `index.html` file and put whatever you want inbetween your main app component's opening and closing tags, including a `style` tag to style the elements which will appear there. This content will disappear when your app loads.

Comment: Do you mean root index.html file? Where placed `<app-root></app-root>`?

Comment: Yes, put it inbetween those tags.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and neater way is to Lazy Loading your modules. You can easily convert your modules to be loaded lazily.

This divides your huge javascript into chunks and does not load them until they are requested.